# Detect picture format with SixLabors ImageSharp

Tags: c#, imagesharp

How do I get the image format using SixLabors.ImageSharp?

In version **1.0.0-alpha9-00152** I could use:

```
Image<Rgba32> image = Image.Load(GetBytesFromBlobStorage());
IImageFormat format = image.CurrentImageFormat;
```

but `.CurrentImageFormat()` doesn't seen to be able in beta version **1.0.0-beta0001**.

I want to know if the image is **.png**, **.bmp** or **.jpeg**.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yeah, we moved your cheese a little bit with **1.0.0-beta0001**.

The signature you are looking for is now.

```cs
public static Image<TPixel> Load<TPixel>(Stream stream, out IImageFormat format)
```

Comment: Will there be a way to check the image format after the image has been loaded? Like the CurrentImageFormat.

Comment: That `IIMageFormat` out parameter gives you exactly that.

Comment: @JamesSouth It is not available **after** the image has been loaded (when you have only one variable - Image)

Comment: @RouR I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Apparently, this was changed after the 1.0.0 release. @JamesSouth what is the way to do the same right now?

Comment: Nope here it is. https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.html#SixLabors_ImageSharp_Image_Load__1_System_IO_Stream_SixLabors_ImageSharp_Formats_IImageFormat__

Comment: You are right, sync Load() does have an "out" argument. I missed that I'm using LoadAsync which does not seems to have it.

Comment: Async methods cannot have out parameters. You need `LoadWithFormatAsync` https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.html#SixLabors_ImageSharp_Image_LoadWithFormatAsync_System_IO_Stream_

Comment: Exactly what I need! Thank you @JamesSouth

Comment: No worries, happy to help

Comment: I currently use the 2.1.0 version.

From what I've seen so far I have to keep the IImageFormat in a variable while loading the image. It seems there is no way to detect what the format is, just having an Image variable. 

Is that correct?

Comment: Use Identify. There’s API docs btw

Answer (score 5):

If you only need to detect format without loading the whole image there is a method `DetectFormatAsync`:

```
public static Task<IImageFormat> DetectFormatAsync(Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
```

Comment: Correct as of SixLabors.ImageSharp version 3+. It worked for me.