# How to extract, upcast and process an array of bytes from GetPixelSpan then save back to a file?

Tags: f#, .net-core, imagesharp

This is probably a really simple matter, but I can't quite figure out how to put the pieces together.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50025908/convert-imagergba32-to-byte-using-imagesharp) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807283/detect-picture-format-with-sixlabors-imagesharp) as well as [this page](https://docs.sixlabors.com/articles/ImageSharp/WorkingWithPixelBuffers.html) in the API documentation all somewhat hint at the answer, but I haven't been able to work out what I need from them.

So right now I'm trying to implement a naïve little program to open an image, get the pixels out into an array, process them a bit and then save the updated pixels back as a new image.  In this particular case, I'm wanting to take the average on the 3x3 window around each pixel as a simple blur.  The specific operation isn't too important (there definitely are more efficient ways, I'm specifically trying to write a naïve version right now for later comparison against other versions), but I haven't been able to work out how to make this happen.  Right now what I have is:

```
let accessClampedArrayWithDefault (arr: uint32[][]) width height def x y : uint32[] =
    if x < 0 || x > width-1 || y < 0 || y > height-1 then
        def
    else
        arr.[x + width * y]

let extractPixelParts (p: Rgba32) =
    let R = uint32 p.R
    let G = uint32 p.G
    let B = uint32 p.B
    let A = uint32 p.A
    [|R; G; B; A|]

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    use img = Image.Load(@"D:\Users\sampleimage.jpg")    
    let mutable out_img = img.Clone()    
    let pxs = img.GetPixelSpan().ToArray() |> Array.map extractPixelParts    
    let mutable (nps: uint32[][]) = Array.zeroCreate pxs.Length    
    let ac = accessClampedArrayWithDefault pxs img.Width img.Height [|0u;0u;0u;0u|]

    for x in 0..img.Width-1 do
        for y in 0..img.Height-1 do
            let p = ac x y
            for z in -1..1 do
                for w in -1..1 do
                    let q = ac (x + z) (y + w)
                    nps.[x + y * img.Width] <- Array.zip p q |> Array.map (fun (a,b) -> a + b)
            nps.[x + y * img.Width] <- Array.map (fun i -> float i / 9.0 |> uint32 ) nps.[x + y * img.Width]

    let rpx = Array.collect (fun a -> Array.map byte a) nps

    let out_img = Image.Load<Rgba32>(img.GetConfiguration(), rpx, Formats.Jpeg.JpegDecoder())

    printfn "out_img's width is %d and height is %d" out_img.Width out_img.Height
```

but it is failing with an exception on the `let out_img =` line.  If I don't include the JpegDecoder part then I get an error message about a missing decoder, but if I do include it then I get an error message about a missing SOI.

So, my question is, how can I pull out pixels and work with them/each channel in a larger variable size than 8 bits (e.g. 32 bits) so that I can perform intermediate operations that cannot be represented in 8 bits per channel, before converting the final result back to bytes, and then reconstituting that back to something that can be saved to disk as an image?

I have quite possibly forgotten to mention something important, so please do feel free to ask for clarifications :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with F#, but looks like there are several issues:

- The line `Image.Load<Rgba32>(img.GetConfiguration(), rpx, Formats.Jpeg.JpegDecoder())` will try to **decode** a Jpeg-encoded in-memory stream (provided as `byte[]`).
- Regarding your question:

  > so that I can perform intermediate operations that cannot be represented in 8 bits per channel

Why don't you just work on the `Rgba32[]`array? 
There is no need for the `extractPixelParts ...` stuff. Storing all your pixels in a jagged array (`uint32[][]`) will lead to a very slow code execution because of the unnecessary heap allocations.

**EDIT:**
Sorry, I misunderstood this point. If you need higher precison for intermediate operations, I suggest to use `Vector4`! you can use `pixel.ToVector4()` and `pixel.PackFromVector4(...)`

#### My suggestion (still not optimized but probably easy to understand):

1. Do not copy the image. Just create an **`Rgba32[]` (!!!)** array by `let pxs = img.GetPixelSpan().ToArray()`
2. Process the values inside the array using the formula `arr[y * Width + x] = CreateMyNewRgbaPixelValueAtXY(....)` where `CreateMyNewRgbaPixelValueAtXY(...)` should return an `Rgba32`
3. Return a new image by `Image.LoadPixelData(pxs)`. The `LoadPixelData` method will create a new image by copying your `pxs: Rgba32[]` data into it.
4. **Dispose your original image!**

#### EDIT 2

In order to perform intermediate operation in an efficient way, I suggest the following:

- Create a `inputPixelData:Vector4[]` for your intermediate array filled by invoking `pixel.ToVector4()` for each input pixel
- Create an other array `outputPixelData:Vector4[]` and fill it by processing `inputPixelData`
- Pack `outputPixelData` back into an `pixels:Rgba32[]` array using `.PackFromVector4(outputPixelData[y * Width + x])` (Don't know what's the best way for this in F#)
- `Image.LoadPixelData(pixels)`

There is probably a better way, but I'm unfamiliar with F#.

Comment: Yes, got it working with your input!  Thank you very much :)